Docusign (PHP SDK) Envelope Creation: RECIPIENTS_NOT_PROVIDED
I'm attempting to create a Docusign envelope from a template using the PHP sdk e-sign client:
$apiClient = new ApiClient($config);

// Create an Envelope from a template
$templateId = env('TEMPLATE_ID');
$accountId = env('API_ACCOUNT_ID');
$envelopeApi = new EnvelopesApi($apiClient);
$templateRole = new TemplateRole([
    'email' => 'john@example.com',  // recipient's email
    'name' => 'John Doe',      // recipient's name
    'roleName' => 'User',      // The role name as defined in the template
]);

$envelopeDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition([
    'status' => 'sent',
    'templateId' => $templateId,
    'templateRoles' => [$templateRole]
]);
$envelopeSummary = $envelopeApi->createEnvelope($accountId, $envelopeDefinition);

Produces: Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code [400] with response: RECIPIENTS_NOT_PROVIDED - No recipients were found in the request
From the logs I can see this uses the endpoint POST /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes and seems to contain all necessary parameters according to the docs. The parameters also seem to be consistent with those expected in other languages/sdks.
I'm expecting $envelopeSummary (on a successful call) to include the envelopeId, status, statusDateTime, and uri which I'll then use to create the embedded signing ceremony.
I've verified that the roleName is set to 'User' on the template.

Fixed the code for you, note role_name instead of roleName
    $apiClient = new ApiClient($config);
    
    // Create an Envelope from a template
    $templateId = env('TEMPLATE_ID');
    $accountId = env('API_ACCOUNT_ID');
    $envelopeApi = new EnvelopesApi($apiClient);
    $templateRole = new TemplateRole([
        'email' => 'john@example.com',  // recipient's email
        'name' => 'John Doe',      // recipient's name
        'role_name' => 'User',      // The role name as defined in the template
    ]);

$envelopeDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition([
    'status' => 'sent',
    'templateId' => $templateId,
    'templateRoles' => [$templateRole]
]);
$envelopeSummary = $envelopeApi->createEnvelope($accountId, $envelopeDefinition);


https://i.imgur.com/lCOEiNG.png this is what I have for recipients. I've confirmed the template ID matches the name with the API. Here's what recipients looks like from that same API call: https://i.imgur.com/qseg6cq.png. Given I'm using the same access token to get the template as I am to try to create the envelope I think I can rule out any environment mixups.

The API call you show in the second image does not have templateRoles, can you show the API call that matches the code above?

I'm using GET https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{API_ACCOUNT_ID}/templates/{TEMPLATE_ID}. Where would I expect to find the template roles in the response if they were there? Which ones do I need and how can I add them?

OK, there's confusion here. The endpoint in your last comment is a GET to obtain information about a template. That is not what I'm asking. I'm asking about the POST call that you do via the SDK to create an envelope.

I think your issue is that it's not roleName but rather role_name, let me update my answer

Apologies for the confusion. Because the SDK abstracts the POST API call I can't actually see it -- I only know it posts to /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{API_ACCOUNT_ID}/envelopes from the limited information in the docusign logs. I appreciate your efforts and I tried changing roleName to role_name in the TemplateRole parameter but unfortunately I'm getting the same error.

You can go to your docusign account and download API logs to see what API is sent exactly. https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301=&bundleId=jux1643235969954&topicId=poz1578456669909.html&_LANG=enus
